# Neo4J how to add a relationship between 2 nodes that already exist

Tags: neo4j, nodes

i have a little problem with neo4j and i don't know how to resolve it.

I use the sintax:
`create(p1)-[:wow]->(p2)` and it works fine, this actually make a relationship between node `p1` and node `p2`, but what if I want to make a relatioship between the first one and the third?

When I try with `create(p1)-[:wow]->(p3)` it create something like 4 more nodes that I don't want. What can I do?

[image: Example]

for example in this image how can i make a relation ship between node 1 and 3 without make any other nodes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first match your nodes then create relation between them:

You created nodes:

```
CREATE (a:Foo{name:"foo"}), (b:Bar{name:"bar"})
```

Then you want to create relation between them:

```
MATCH (f:Foo{name:"foo"}), (h:Bar{name:"bar"})
with f,h
CREATE (f)-[:LOVES]->(h)
```

If you don't match the nodes before, Neo4j will create those nodes for you.

Comment: Why in 'MATCH (f:Foo{name:"foo"}), (h:Bar{name:"bar}) with f,h' you use f and h intead of a and b that you created?

Comment: To show you that those are only variable names, not identifiers d'or thé nodes you created.

Comment: @ziopera remember to tag the answer as resolved, so the questions is not in "not answered" section anymore.

Comment: This solution doesn't account for the relationship already existing. If you run it more than once, it will produce multiple `:LOVES` relationships. Also, several syntax errors (I fixed those via edits).

Comment: sorry for typos I made this answer using mobile phone, and thank you for fixing it :). You're right regarding the multiple relations created if there is only one but it may be intended. The problem here was to create a relation between two nodes without creating the nodes again. But you could want to create multiple relations between two nodes.

Comment: To avoid creating duplicate nodes or relationships, you'll want to use MERGE instead of CREATE, and it's best to use MERGES piecemeal: MERGE each node of the pattern separately, then MERGE the relationship between the node identifiers that were previously merged. Similar to the codeblock in this answer, just replace every MATCH and CREATE with MERGE.

Comment: Of course you should use merge if you don't want duplicates, but my example here is with an empty database.